# How to modify existing variable and also import new variables using import *

Tags: python, django, list

I have a file `test.py` with

```
list_sample = [1,2,4]
```

Now, I want to append to the list from another file

eg: test2.py

```
list_sample =+ [10,11]

# also I have many other things in this script
a=10
c=10+a
```

and modify `test.py` as

```
list_sample = [1,2,4]

# I want to import all the variables from test2.py but also append the list_sample
# I cant do that directly in this file. Because this is like blueprint
from .test2 import *

print(a+30)
print(list_sample)
```

But this gives an error list_sample not defined

The only way I can do this  change test2.py to

```
list_sample = [1,2,4,10,11]

# also I have many other things in this script
a=10
c=10+a
```

One more option i have is change test2.py to

```
from .test import list_sample

list_sample += [10,11]

# also I have many other things in this script
a=10
c=10+a
```

but this will lead to circular imports

**Conclusion**

This is not possible so then i decided to just go like this. Add some segregation in the `test2.py`

```
# variables from master file
# copy them from the test.py
list_sample = [1,2,3]

# changes to variables from master file
list_sample =+ [10,11]

# new variables
a=10
c=10+a
```

**Reason I want this**

In Django i have `settings.py` and in that i have `INSTALLED_APPS` list

I use `django_extensions` while working on my pc, but when i share this code to others i dont want the other to depend on `django_extensions`

Generally in `settings.py` we can manipulate by using `DEGUB=True` i.e

```
if DEBUG=True:
    INSTALLED_APPS =+ INSTALLED_APPS+["django_extensions"]
```

but this is w.r.t to `DEBUG`

but what i am looking is w.r.t to different people all using `DEBUG=TRUE`

so for that i have seen someone doing like below

`setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ordered_model',

    # new apps created
    'users',
    'apps',
]


if os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "custom_settings.py")):
    from .custom_settings.py import *
```

and in `custom_settings.py` add `INSTALLED_APPS` full with `django_extensions`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ordered_model',

    # new apps created
    'users',
    'apps',
    'django_extensions'
]
```

I was planning to make this more generic type, so any project i am working i just copy paste `custom_settings.py` file into the folder with `settings.py` and do my work and again remove `custom_settings.py` or (add in gitignore), so the other person who works with this code, dont have to bother about my settings.

So now i will adjust like this in `custom_settings.py`

```
# THIS PART MANUALLY COPY PASTE FROM settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ........  COPY PASTE FROM settings.py
]

# my additional apps i want to use
INSTALLED_APPS =+ ["django_extension"]
```

Comment: That's just not good practice.  `test2.py` should contain functions that make your changes, and `test.py` can import and run them.

Comment: thats the requirement. i have to add some new variables and also able to change some previous variables

Comment: Then you don't understand the requirement.  Python doesn't work that way.  A module doesn't have access to another modules globals.  Names have to be imported.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). What's the *exact* requirement you're trying to fulfill? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I can do `from .test import list_sample`  inside `test2.py` and modify it, but will that not lead to circular import

Comment: I run python codes on different systems. So certain things which need extra packages those things i want to segretate into another file

Comment: @Santhosh: It will. Which is where the XY problem comes in. It's unclear why you're doing this, and it's likely your reasons for doing so are mistaken.

Comment: i am using DJango. I have `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the settings.py. now i want to append few things to this  `INSTALLED_APPS` list, through a separte file without touching this and only calling import *. Anyhow this is not possible i can see

Comment: It's _intentionally_ difficult because this is "spooky action at a distance" and _shouldn't_ be easy. People don't expect importing a namespace to change things in other namespaces.

Comment: @Santhosh Please edit to include what you mentioned in your most recent comment. I also recommend adding the [tag:django] tag, since I'm sure other Django devs have had similar problems.

Comment: @Santhosh why not simply use environment variables? If some environment variable is set to some value then you will add `django_extension` to the installed apps. Also there is no `=+` operator it is `+=`...

Comment: i want to keep the settings.py clean

Comment: @Santhosh and wildcard imports and trying to modify other modules variables is clean code? And what is not clean about using environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to import a list from another module then append to that list and finally you want that list to be updated in both modules.

One solution is that you should place this list outside `.py` file, for example place it inside a `.json` file. In this way you can open the file change the list and save that list again and you can use that file in any module.